# About python re

Tags: python-3.5

I use the online regular tool on the Internet, and it shows the right results.
But when I use python's re package, the results are different.

```
pattern = re.compile(u'(?<=slot).*?(?=(}]}}]|$))')
result = pattern.findall(data)
print(result)
```

I want to get a string that ends with '}]}}]' beginning with 'slot'

Comment: What is `data`?  What result do you get, and what result do you expect?

Comment: Not every regular expression library is the same, although this looks to be a perfectly normal PCRE.

Answer (score 0):

What your Regular Expression:

```
u'(?<=slot).*?(?=(}]}}]|$))'
```

does, is matching every sequence *.*?*, in a non-greedy way, such that the sequence is preceded by *slot* and is followed by these symbols *}]}}]* or by the end of the text *$*.
In the following example string I put in bold the matches, for this RegExp:

"Crazy Train slot **Spider's Lullabyes**  }]}}]"

To achieve what you want you can use the following pattern:

```
pattern = re.compile(u'(?<=^slot).*(?=}]}}]$)')
```

The caret (^) ensures that you search *slot* from the very beginning, and the operator (?<...) discards *slot* from result. After that: you match everything .* until reach the end with the desired final *}]}}]*, the operator (?=...) discards *}]}}]* of the result.

The match for the following text is put in bold:

"slot **Spider's Lullabyes**  }]}}]"